# How to merge two 2 dimensional arrays with Jquery

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I want to merge the oldData and newData. Need to show output by sorting date as ascending. If data is available in both, add as [date , oldValue , New value]. If data available in newData only then create like [ '2018-03-30', null, 5 ]

```
var oldData = [ [ '2018-04-01', 10 ], [ '2018-04-02', 20 ], [ '2018-04-03', 30 ] ];
var newData = [ [ '2018-03-30',  5 ], [ '2018-03-31',  6 ], [ '2018-04-01', 22 ] ];
```

The desired output would be:

```
[ [ '2018-03-30', null, 5 ], [ '2018-03-31', null,  6 ], [ '2018-04-01', 10, 22 ] , [ '2018-04-02', 20, null ] , [ '2018-04-03', 30, null ] ];
```

Please help me achieve this in jquery / java-script.

Comment: from where comes those `null` inside the expected output?
And let me understand, you want to merge the oldData and newData arrays?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: @CalvinNunes Assuming null in pos 1 it was not in oldData, in pos 2 not in new data

Comment: Ok, now i know you want to merge, but still don't understand those `null`, what is a "missing value" ?

Comment: Can you explain *in words* what you are trying to achieve?  If you can do that, you'll find you're quite a long way towards a solution.  At the moment, all you've provided is a before and after with no rules/explanation.  Any code provided would be a guess that will likely only fit these exact values instead of the actual problem you are trying to achieve.

Comment: So you want to [concatenate two arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) right ?

Comment: I want to merge the oldData  and newData. Need to show output by sorting date as ascending. If data is available in both, add as [date , oldValue , New value].  If data available in newData only then create like [ '2018-03-30', null, 5 ]

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like that:

```
let output = [];
oldData.map(e => output.push([new String(e[0]), e[1], null]));

for(const elem of newData) {
  output.map(e => {
    if(e[0] === elem[0]) {
      e[2] = elem[1];
      continue;
    }
  })
  output.push([new String(elem[0]), null, elem[1]]);
}
```

You create new array with the values from the `oldData`, in a desired structure (I user `new String()` to make sure I don't just copy a reference - remove if not needed).
Then you loop over the elements of `newData` to see if `ouptut` already has an elem. with that date.
If so, you change the `null` inside it to a number from coresponding element.
If not, you just push a new one with given date, null and a number.

Remeber that this will work properly only when the items are unique!